# Moving object in space

Tags: orbit, atmospheric-drag

I am a learner in this field. I have a doubt after watching movie "Gravity". In that movie, an explosion occurs in a spacecraft and the particles of that vehicle move so faster than a bullet, (*as mentioned by George in that movie*) from a very long distance to the spot where the astronauts (*actors*) crew members are.

My question is will those objects (*or parts of spacecraft*) stops/slow down ever?

What I think right now is they don't stop because when Sandra (*actress*) goes into rotations, she just doesn't stop until George (*actor*) helps her out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each of the exploded debris will gain a given $\Delta$V based on the force from the explosion. This $\Delta$V will be comparatively small to the orbital velocity, typically you'd be looking at 100s of meters per second against 1000s. Objects in orbit stay in orbit ALMOST indefinitely. Drag is the best friend of gravity. Gravity stops these object escaping the Earth, they have to be moving a lot faster to get away from the gravity pull. But it keeps them in orbit going around and around the Earth. Each time a object orbits the Earth it might hit a few very sparsely spread atoms. These atoms collide with the debris and slow it down. Over a period of months, years, decades, etc all objects in orbit will eventually reenter the atmosphere. Low Earth orbit is a couple of months, or years. Geosynchronous orbit is more like millions and billions of years.

Short answer: Yes, eventually they will slow down and reenter the Earth's atmosphere.

Comment: *"Objects in orbit stay in orbit ALMOST indefinitely"* -- Probably worth mentioning that isn't some special property of orbits, just plain old inertia.

Comment: The fact that the Earth doesn't have a uniform gravity field will impact the orbit as well, but I don't know enough about that to speak in any more detail

Comment: @called2voyage very true! The point I was trying to make is that things in orbit don't fall to the ground due to gravity.

Comment: @Nickolai it will certainly have an impact on the orbit, but the effect is conservative so it wont decrease/effect the orbital life time!

Comment: **All** objects in orbit eventually reenter the atmosphere? An object in geosynchronous orbit will re-enter the earth's atmosphere after millions and billions of years? I don't think this is right.

Comment: @HopDavid Outside of the highly unlikely (and statistically negligible) chance of an object in geo being struck by an object with hyperbolic velocity and exchanging enough momentum to give the geo object escape velocity, things never get further away (without active intervention). Now although the likelihood of high momentum extremely elastic exchanges in geo is small, the likelihood of random particles is much larger. Collision with these particles is a special type of drag, but it is analogous to normal drag in that given enough time, your craft will lose enough velocity to re-enter.

Comment: "things never get further away (without active intervention)" See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_acceleration . The orbits of objects below synchronous orbit will steadily shrink, orbits above synchronous will steadily move away from the primary.

Comment: Phobos' orbit is slowly dropping. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phobos_%28moon%29#Predicted_destruction in 30 to 50 million years it's thought this moon will hit Mars. But this is attributed to tidal acceleration (see comment above).

Comment: @HopDavid I'm of course talking about objects orbiting the Earth, since that's what the questions specified. Also nothing you've said so far disagrees with my statement: "Objects in orbit stay in orbit ALMOST indefinitely".  Also since the vast, vast majority of man made objects are much, much closer to the Earth than the Moon is, it would be reductive to include this aspect in the answer. If however someone were to ask at what altitude range do these two forces become close to equal then this negligible effect would be beneficial to include.

Comment: @HopDavid ... on top of the fact that the it's mostly negligible due to the location of the objects, it's also mostly negligible due to the mass and coefficient of drag of most objects. The moon is massive, in the truest form of the word, the heaviest man made object in orbit at the moment is the ISS. The moon is 1.6*10^17 times more massive and the moon is pretty much a sphere - hence it has a much, much higher ballistic coefficient, making it harder to perturb by drag.

Comment: What? My comment on tidal acceleration doesn't apply to earth? You said "**all** objects in orbit will eventually reenter the atmosphere." This simply isn't true.

Comment: @HopDavid you're talking about semantics unrelated to the question. I can do it to though; you said "The orbits of objects below synchronous orbit will steadily shrink" - But what if I turn on my engines and move to a higher orbit, that's not steadily shrinking is it? It's pointless for me to make the argument because it clearly isn't the point you were making.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14537/discussion-between-hopdavid-and-fraserofsmeg)